# identifying current passenger actions / interpreting passenger-status output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

We frequently have what we call "apache hangs", where our passenger queue starts to grow like crazy, and the application appears not to be responding. We believe that it due to all passenger processes happening to be serving very long running requests simultaneously.

We are trying to figure out how to identify what the actual current request is that each active passenger process is currently trying to serve. Note that I have read Phusion's [frozen process blog](http://old.blog.phusion.nl/2012/09/21/the-right-way-to-deal-with-frozen-processes-on-unix/), and am still digesting it, experimenting with SIGQUIT and other suggestions there.

My question here is, can `passenger-status --show=server` tell me what each process is doing, and if so, can anyone here help me understand how to interpret its results.

It looks to me like this command is reporting a ton of stuff that is *not* actually going on at the moment, in addition to whatever is, and I can't figure out how to suss out what of this really are current requests being handled by active passenger processes.

The output of `passenger-status --show=server` is too long to past here, so here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/avramd/a65dd1d015d3388c4606), including the base `passenger-status` output too.